# Draw several triangles in cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am trying to draw several triangles in one instance with cesium. My code works for drawing only one triangle but when I extend the positions (for two or many triangles) I get errors.

```
    var extent = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(100, 30, 108, 36);
    Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = extent;
    Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR = 0.5;

    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
        navigationHelpButton: false, animation: false, timeline: false
    });

    // original sample begins here
    var mypositions = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([
        -94.6714,35.9641,322.543,
        -94.6717,35.9642,325.51,
        -94.6717, 35.9639, 324.724,
        -94.6717,35.9639,324.717,
        -94.6717,35.9639,324.724,
        -94.6717,35.9639,324.719 ]);

    // unroll 'mypositions' into a flat array here
    var numPositions = mypositions.length;

    var pos = new Float64Array(numPositions * 3);
    for (var i = 0; i < numPositions; ++i) {
        pos[i * 3] = mypositions[i].x;
        pos[i * 3 + 1] = mypositions[i].y;
        pos[i * 3 + 2] = mypositions[i].z;
    }

    var geometry = new Cesium.Geometry({
        attributes: {
            position: new Cesium.GeometryAttribute({
                componentDatatype: Cesium.ComponentDatatype.DOUBLE, // not FLOAT
                componentsPerAttribute: 3,
                values: pos
            }),
            normal: new Cesium.GeometryAttribute({
                componentDatatype: Cesium.ComponentDatatype.FLOAT,
                componentsPerAttribute: 3,
                values: new Float32Array([255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0])
            })

        },



        indices: new Uint32Array([0, 1, 2]),
        primitiveType: Cesium.PrimitiveType.TRIANGLES,
        boundingSphere: Cesium.BoundingSphere.fromVertices(pos)
    });


    var myInstance = new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
        geometry: geometry,
        attributes: {
            color: Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(Cesium.Color.RED)

        },

        show: new Cesium.ShowGeometryInstanceAttribute(true)
    });





    viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Primitive({
        geometryInstances: [myInstance],
        asynchronous: false,
            appearance: new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance({
            closed: true,
            translucent: false

        })
    }));
```

And the error I get is:

> All attributes lists must have the same number of attributes.

How can I extend this code to draw multiple triangles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is telling you that the positions, normals, and indices (if present) must all agree on the total number of points.  In the case above, you've provided normal vectors and indices for only one of the two triangles.

Actually you don't need to provide indices if your triangles don't share a vertex anywhere.  So, I've commented that line out in the code below, and wrote normal vectors for all triangles.

Note that this is the lowest-level way to create geometry in Cesium, there are much easier ways at the higher level, for example [CZML Polygons](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML%20Polygon.html&label=CZML) or [Entity.polygon](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html#polygon).

Still, here's a copy of your code with some issues fixed:

```js
var extent = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-98, 30, -90, 39);
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = extent;
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR = 0.5;

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
  navigationHelpButton: false, animation: false, timeline: false
});

var mypositions = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([
  // Triangle A
  -90.6714, 35.9641, 322.543,
  -94.6717, 38.9642, 325.51,
  -97.6717, 35.9639, 324.724,
  // Triangle B
  -94.6717, 30.9639, 324.717,
  -90.6717, 32.9639, 324.724,
  -94.6717, 34.9639, 324.719 ]);

// unroll 'mypositions' into a flat array here
var numPositions = mypositions.length;

var pos = new Float64Array(numPositions * 3);
var normals = new Float32Array(numPositions * 3);
for (var i = 0; i < numPositions; ++i) {
  pos[i * 3] = mypositions[i].x;
  pos[i * 3 + 1] = mypositions[i].y;
  pos[i * 3 + 2] = mypositions[i].z;
  normals[i * 3] = 0.0;
  normals[i * 3 + 1] = 0.0;
  normals[i * 3 + 2] = 1.0;
}

var geometry = new Cesium.Geometry({
  attributes: {
    position: new Cesium.GeometryAttribute({
      componentDatatype: Cesium.ComponentDatatype.DOUBLE, // not FLOAT
      componentsPerAttribute: 3,
      values: pos
    }),
    normal: new Cesium.GeometryAttribute({
      componentDatatype: Cesium.ComponentDatatype.FLOAT,
      componentsPerAttribute: 3,
      values: normals
    })

  },

  // Don't need the following line if no vertices are shared.
  //indices: new Uint32Array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
  primitiveType: Cesium.PrimitiveType.TRIANGLES,
  boundingSphere: Cesium.BoundingSphere.fromVertices(pos)
});

var myInstance = new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
  geometry: geometry,
  attributes: {
    color: Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(Cesium.Color.RED)
  },
  show: new Cesium.ShowGeometryInstanceAttribute(true)
});

viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Primitive({
  geometryInstances: [myInstance],
  asynchronous: false,
  appearance: new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance({
    closed: true,
    translucent: false
  })
}));
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.16/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.16/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! But in case the triangles share vertices, what role does this indices have. according to cesium it does : Optional index data that determines the primitives in the geometry. But what does it mean

Comment: Try deleting the last position (-94.6717, 34.9639, 324.719) from Triangle B.  That triangle disappears because it no longer has 3 points.  Next, add `indices: new Uint32Array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0])` and a similar triangle appears!  Triangle A uses points 0, 1, 2, just as before, but now Triangle B uses points 3, 4, and 0, re-using the first point from Triangle A.